# ruby on rails net ssh strickhostkeychecking=no

Tags: ruby-on-rails, net-ssh

Hi i have a `net:ssh` connection in the `controller`. I might change the `host name` dynamically while establishing the connection. But when it logs in for the first time, shell might ask permission whether to connect or not. Since iam connecting to it through the web, i could not see any pop up asking me. 
Hence i read 
https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.tcl/browse_thread/thread/ca0cd6ec905eb702
and i want to add `"-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no"` this tag while connecting to the host. 
As we know the below is the standard format of net::ssh in rails

```
     @HOST = 'hostname'
     @USER = 'username'
     @PASS = 'password'

     Net::SSH.start( @HOST, @USER, :password => @PASS ) do|ssh|
```

Where would i pass this extra parameter `"-oStrictHostKeyChecking=no"` while establishing the connection?

I already tried

```
@HOST = 'hostname -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

But it does not work.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use ruby's begin/rescue like following, which will handle the host key mismatch by remembering the host and retrying the connection.

```
begin
  Net::SSH.start(@host, @user, :password => @pass) do |ssh|
    ... #what ever you want to do
  end
rescue Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch => e
  e.remember_host!
  retry
end
```